# In Spring Boot 2, how can I auto-generate my database and also record the schema generation commands to a file?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1 with Java 11.  I am using Maven to build my artifacts.  When running locally, I like the Spring JPA directives that let me create the database automatically ...

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

I also like the directives that let me auto-create files ...

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=update
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=update.sql
```

However when I combine both in my src/main/resources/application.properties ...

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${PG_DB_HOST:localhost}:5432/${PG_DB_NAME}

spring.datasource.username=${PG_DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${PG_DB_PASS}

spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=update
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=update.sql
```

it seems the "spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence" take precedence and my schema changes are not auto-run against the database.  Is there a way to configure things such that both happen -- the changes get recorded to a file and automatically run against my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the *database.action* with *javax.persistence* as follows which will update the database schema according to models as explained in [Database Schema Creation](http://Database%20Schema%20Creation)

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=update
```

Also recommended to change *(Deprecated)* `PostgreSQLDialect` dialect with `PostgreSQL82Dialect` or according to the version you are using. [Dailects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${PG_DB_HOST:localhost}:5432/${PG_DB_NAME}

spring.datasource.username=${PG_DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${PG_DB_PASS}

spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=update
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=update
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=update.sql
```

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot and I'm reading that persistence.xml is ignored by Spring Boot -- https://medium.com/@nieldw/jpa-spring-boot-will-not-search-for-meta-inf-persistence-xml-f28f14444d6d .  Is there a way to include that property as part of the application.properties file?

Comment: Yes it is, I have added for someone who is using the xml configurations. As your project consists of application properties file you only have to include `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=update` as described in the answer